# Typescript - Manual refresh textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, textarea, reload

I have a `textarea` with `height: auto;`. However, when I reset the `[ngModel]` variable associated with that textarea (e.g. `this.myNgModelVar = "";`) the height of the textarea would not automatically decrease until the user starts typing again.

Since I could not figure out any solution to this, I figured out I might just want to refresh the `<textarea>`. But the question is, on Typescript, how can I refresh/update it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack that I use to recreate DOM elements, but some people don't like it.

```
<textarea *ngFor="let x of refresh"></textarea>
```

Then in your component.

```
@Component({...})
export public MyComponent {
     public refresh = [1];

     public constructor(private change: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

     public refreshTextArea() {
        this.refresh[0]++;
        this.change.markForCheck();
     }
}
```

This works because `*ngFor` will update the collection of DOM elements when the array is changed. We use `this.refresh[0]++` above to modify the first element which triggers the `*ngFor` to recreate the DOM element. The array has only one element so just one `<textarea>` will be created.

It can be confusing to other Angular developers who see this. So be sure to add comments explaining why you're doing it.

The alternative is to use `*ngIf` and a `setTimeout` to toggle a boolean value from `false` to `true` and allow Angular to re-render the DOM elements. That's a lot more code and even more confusing (if you ask me).

Comment: I have just tried the code provided. Strangely, when I call the `refreshTextArea()` method, the `textarea` does not change. Perhaps I am not doing something correctly. I am supposed to store the code provided above in my exported class, right?

Comment: @Smitherson I've updated my answer to use a the `ChangeDetectorRef`. This will tell Angular that the view needs to be re-rendered.

Comment: @Smitherson I'm sorry, but I made a mistake in my original answer. The `.slice()` will notify `ngFor` that the array has changed, but you have to modify the array element to trigger the DOM element to be recreated. So I increment the number instead.

Comment: I have just tried it again. Strangely, my textarea disappeared. It's not even rendered on the view. Any ideas on why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the Text Area, Include ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor of your component:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

Thereafter wherever you wish to refresh, just call

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```